# emberjs dynamic route segment undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I have a problem with emberJS dynamic segment route. 
My router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
"use strict";
this.resource('signin', {path: '/'});
this.resource('index', {path: '/users'}, function () {
    this.route('create');
    this.route('display', {path: "/display", queryParams: ['filter', 'pageSize', 'page']});
    this.route('edit', { path: '/edit/:user_id' });
    this.route('delete', { path: '/delete/:user_id'});
    this.route('details', { path: '/details/:user_id', queryParams: ['filter', 'pageSize', 'page']});
});...
```

So now, when user goes to "details" route I get user_id and save it to localStorage like this:

```
App.IndexDetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function (params, queryParams) {
    "use strict";
    var ownerId = params.user_id || queryParams.user_id || localStorage.ownerId;
    localStorage.ownerId = ownerId;  //save current userID used later on create product form
    return this.store.find('product', { fields: queryParams });
}, /*just added this code and all start work :) */ serialize : function () { "use strict"; return { user_id : localStorage.ownerId }; }});
```

Next in controller I want to do some filtering, and after reload view for changes:

```
App.IndexDetailsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
content: ["index", "indexDisplay"],
entryNotAllowed: true,
fields : {
    "filter" : null,
    "pageSize" : 10,
    "page" : 0
},
actions: {
    refreshUsersTable : function () {
        "use strict";
        var that = this, call, pageSize, page, filter, ownerId;
        pageSize = this.get("fields.pageSize");
        page = this.get("fields.page");
        filter = this.get("fields.filter");
        ownerId = localStorage.ownerId;
        this.transitionToRoute('index.details', {user_id: ownerId, queryParams : {filter : filter, pageSize: pageSize, page : page}});
    }

}});
```

Problem is, that when I call refreshUsersTable method I get filter/pageSize/page refreshed in URL, but dynamic segment is "undefined".

So, what is wrong here? Help please :)

Comment: Ok, I find out this :) `serialize` solve a problem. I added to my route this `,
    serialize : function () {
        "use strict";
        return {
            user_id : localStorage.ownerId
        };
    }`

Comment: Will you add that as your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sure, I added this line to my code :)

Comment: no, I mean down below, you can add an answer to your own question :)